# m1 mac, calling nanosleep from assembly

Tags: macos, assembly, system-calls, apple-m1, arm64

I would like to call something like nanosleep from assembly, using only SVC calls. But it is not obvious how to do it using only the limited information I have, this list of macos syscall call signatures:
https://opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-1504.3.12/bsd/kern/syscalls.master

I tried to figure out what C does when calling nanosleep and I was able to reduce it to this:

```
struct timespec {  long tv_sec;  long tv_nsec; };

int nanosleep(const struct timespec *__rqtp, struct timespec *__rmtp)
__asm("_" "nanosleep" );

int main() {
    struct timespec remaining, request = { 3, 1 };
    int response = nanosleep(&request, &remaining); }
```

I am not sure what that `__asm` does as that does not look like assembly. Anyway I found an implementation of `nanosleep` in Apples libc source code. It relies on a call to `clock_get_time` though and that isn't defined in libc. I found a mention of `clock_get_time` in the XNU source code, but this is in a .defs file, which I don't know what is and it doesn't seem have an implementation.

In any case, is there some better documentation on the SVC calls, or some place I can find the assembly for the libc SVC implementation?

Any information or ideas are much appreciated.

Comment: It overrides the asm symbol name to `_nanosleep`.  IDK why; MacOS name mangling would already do that.  https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Asm-Labels.html#index-assembler-names-for-identifiers  - clang supports the same GNU C extension.  Perhaps there was a macro there which you've expanded manually.

Comment: `_nanosleep` is not implemented through a `svc` call.  It's done with a special page holding the current time.

Comment: @fuz, interesting, do you have any more information about this? I know there are special registers holding cycle counts for example, but I haven't heard about a special page. And even if you got the time from a special page, that wouldn't in itself "sleep" the execution?

Comment: @BasicBlock I've single-stepped through the kernel to check for this and found that it did not do any `svc` calls.

Comment: @fuz, I completely believe you! I just meant, do you have any information about the special page? Also which tool are you using to step debug into the kernel? (sorry I am still a noob with this)

Comment: @BasicBlock Sorry, I don't.  I used the LLVM debugger lldb.

Comment: @fuz: That's odd; I'd have expected `nanosleep` to enter the kernel if the sleep is longer than a tiny duration, like a a few tens or  hundred microseconds that would be worth putting the CPU to sleep for or even scheduling some other task on the CPU.  Maybe you used a short enough duration for it to choose to busy-wait in user-space?  And when single-stepping, that duration will pass in one iteration of the spin loop.

Comment: @PeterCordes Likely it does so for longer sleeps.  The code was quite complex.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First off, let's get the title of your question out of the way. The way you call `nanosleep` from assembly is like this:

```
mov x8, 3
stp x8, xzr, [sp, -0x10]!   // 3 seconds, 0 nanoseconds
mov x0, sp
mov x1, 0
bl _nanosleep
add sp, sp, 0x10
```

You just use the libc implementation. For most purposes, you really shouldn't go to a deeper level, since a) on arm64 you're forced by the OS to link against libSystem (and thus libc) anyway, and b) because the Darwin kernel ABI(s) are not stable.

---

That said, let's look at how it works under the hood.

In the [latest Libc source drop](https://github.com/apple-oss-distributions/Libc/tags), we find that there's actually two implementations of `nanosleep` in `gen/nanosleep.c`: one for `#if __DARWIN_UNIX03`, which uses `clock_get_time`, and one for the other case, which uses `mach_absolute_time` and `mach_wait_until`. The one actually used in production is the former:

```c
int nanosleep(const struct timespec *requested_time, struct timespec *remaining_time) {
    kern_return_t kret;
    int ret;
    mach_timespec_t current;
    mach_timespec_t completion;
   
    if (__unix_conforming == 0)
        __unix_conforming = 1;

#ifdef VARIANT_CANCELABLE
    pthread_testcancel();
#endif /* VARIANT_CANCELABLE */

    if ((requested_time == NULL) || (requested_time->tv_sec < 0) || (requested_time->tv_nsec >= NSEC_PER_SEC)) {
        errno = EINVAL;
        return -1;
    }

    if (remaining_time != NULL) {
        /* once we add requested_time, this will be the completion time */
        kret = clock_get_time(clock_port, &completion);
        if (kret != KERN_SUCCESS) {
            fprintf(stderr, "clock_get_time() failed: %s\n", mach_error_string(kret));
            errno = EINVAL;
            return -1;
        }
    }
    ret = SEMWAIT_SIGNAL(clock_sem, MACH_PORT_NULL, 1, 1, (int64_t)requested_time->tv_sec, (int32_t)requested_time->tv_nsec);    
    if (ret < 0) {
        if (errno == ETIMEDOUT) {
            return 0;
        } else if (errno == EINTR) {
            if (remaining_time != NULL) {
                ret = clock_get_time(clock_port, &current);
                if (ret != KERN_SUCCESS) {
                    fprintf(stderr, "clock_get_time() failed: %s\n", mach_error_string(ret));
                    return -1;
                }
                /* This depends on the layout of a mach_timespec_t and timespec_t being equivalent */
                ADD_MACH_TIMESPEC(&completion, requested_time);
                /* We have to compare first, since mach_timespect_t contains unsigned integers */
                if(CMP_MACH_TIMESPEC(&completion, &current) > 0) {
                    SUB_MACH_TIMESPEC(&completion, &current);
                    remaining_time->tv_sec = completion.tv_sec;
                    remaining_time->tv_nsec = completion.tv_nsec;
                } else {
                    bzero(remaining_time, sizeof(*remaining_time));
                }
            }
        } else {
            errno = EINVAL;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

This ends up in `/usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib` (re-exported by `/usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib`). We can look at the assembly by either using `dlopen`/`dlsym` to dump the bytes, extracting the dylib from the dyld_shared_cache, or grabbing it from the ramdisk:

```
;-- _nanosleep:
0x0000e4d4      7f2303d5       pacibsp
0x0000e4d8      ff0301d1       sub sp, sp, 0x40
0x0000e4dc      f44f02a9       stp x20, x19, [sp, 0x20]
0x0000e4e0      fd7b03a9       stp x29, x30, [sp, 0x30]
0x0000e4e4      fdc30091       add x29, sp, 0x30
0x0000e4e8      f30301aa       mov x19, x1
0x0000e4ec      f40300aa       mov x20, x0
0x0000e4f0      ff7f01a9       stp xzr, xzr, [sp, 0x10]
0x0000e4f4      a80300d0       adrp x8, reloc.__unix_conforming
0x0000e4f8      080140f9       ldr x8, [x8]
0x0000e4fc      090140b9       ldr w9, [x8]
0x0000e500      69000035       cbnz w9, 0xe50c
0x0000e504      29008052       mov w9, 1
0x0000e508      090100b9       str w9, [x8]
0x0000e50c      e5b00194       bl sym.imp.pthread_testcancel
0x0000e510      140300b4       cbz x20, 0xe570
0x0000e514      840240f9       ldr x4, [x20]
0x0000e518      c402f8b7       tbnz x4, 0x3f, 0xe570
0x0000e51c      850640f9       ldr x5, [x20, 8]
0x0000e520      08409952       mov w8, 0xca00
0x0000e524      4873a772       movk w8, 0x3b9a, lsl 16
0x0000e528      bf0008eb       cmp x5, x8
0x0000e52c      22020054       b.hs 0xe570
0x0000e530      330300b4       cbz x19, 0xe594
0x0000e534      48040090       adrp x8, 0x96000
0x0000e538      08112c91       add x8, x8, 0xb04
0x0000e53c      000140b9       ldr w0, [x8]
0x0000e540      e1430091       add x1, sp, 0x10
0x0000e544      c7ae0194       bl sym.imp.clock_get_time
0x0000e548      40020034       cbz w0, 0xe590
0x0000e54c      080400d0       adrp x8, sym._gCRAnnotations
0x0000e550      08210f91       add x8, x8, 0x3c8
0x0000e554      130140f9       ldr x19, [x8]
0x0000e558      c2af0194       bl sym.imp.mach_error_string
0x0000e55c      e00300f9       str x0, [sp]
0x0000e560      610300f0       adrp x1, 0x7d000
0x0000e564      21682b91       add x1, x1, 0xada
0x0000e568      e00313aa       mov x0, x19
0x0000e56c      73100094       bl sym._fprintf
0x0000e570      84ad0194       bl sym.imp.__error
0x0000e574      c8028052       mov w8, 0x16
0x0000e578      080000b9       str w8, [x0]
0x0000e57c      00008012       mov w0, -1
0x0000e580      fd7b43a9       ldp x29, x30, [sp, 0x30]
0x0000e584      f44f42a9       ldp x20, x19, [sp, 0x20]
0x0000e588      ff030191       add sp, sp, 0x40
0x0000e58c      ff0f5fd6       retab
0x0000e590      841640a9       ldp x4, x5, [x20]
0x0000e594      48040090       adrp x8, 0x96000
0x0000e598      08012c91       add x8, x8, 0xb00
0x0000e59c      000140b9       ldr w0, [x8]
0x0000e5a0      01008052       mov w1, 0
0x0000e5a4      22008052       mov w2, 1
0x0000e5a8      23008052       mov w3, 1
0x0000e5ac      d1ad0194       bl sym.imp.__semwait_signal
0x0000e5b0      60feff36       tbz w0, 0x1f, 0xe57c
0x0000e5b4      73ad0194       bl sym.imp.__error
0x0000e5b8      080040b9       ldr w8, [x0]
0x0000e5bc      1ff10071       cmp w8, 0x3c
0x0000e5c0      61000054       b.ne 0xe5cc
0x0000e5c4      00008052       mov w0, 0
0x0000e5c8      eeffff17       b 0xe580
0x0000e5cc      6dad0194       bl sym.imp.__error
0x0000e5d0      080040b9       ldr w8, [x0]
0x0000e5d4      1f110071       cmp w8, 4
0x0000e5d8      c1fcff54       b.ne 0xe570
0x0000e5dc      13fdffb4       cbz x19, 0xe57c
0x0000e5e0      48040090       adrp x8, 0x96000
0x0000e5e4      08112c91       add x8, x8, 0xb04
0x0000e5e8      000140b9       ldr w0, [x8]
0x0000e5ec      e1630091       add x1, sp, 0x18
0x0000e5f0      9cae0194       bl sym.imp.clock_get_time
0x0000e5f4      60010034       cbz w0, 0xe620
0x0000e5f8      080400d0       adrp x8, sym._gCRAnnotations
0x0000e5fc      08210f91       add x8, x8, 0x3c8
0x0000e600      130140f9       ldr x19, [x8]
0x0000e604      97af0194       bl sym.imp.mach_error_string
0x0000e608      e00300f9       str x0, [sp]
0x0000e60c      610300f0       adrp x1, 0x7d000
0x0000e610      21682b91       add x1, x1, 0xada
0x0000e614      e00313aa       mov x0, x19
0x0000e618      48100094       bl sym._fprintf
0x0000e61c      d8ffff17       b 0xe57c
0x0000e620      ea3f9952       mov w10, 0xc9ff
0x0000e624      4a73a772       movk w10, 0x3b9a, lsl 16
0x0000e628      880a40b9       ldr w8, [x20, 8]
0x0000e62c      ec274229       ldp w12, w9, [sp, 0x10]
0x0000e630      0bc08652       mov w11, 0x3600
0x0000e634      ab8cb872       movk w11, 0xc465, lsl 16
0x0000e638      2801080b       add w8, w9, w8
0x0000e63c      09010b0b       add w9, w8, w11
0x0000e640      1f010a6b       cmp w8, w10
0x0000e644      2bc1881a       csel w11, w9, w8, gt
0x0000e648      89d58c1a       cinc w9, w12, gt
0x0000e64c      8c0240b9       ldr w12, [x20]
0x0000e650      e81b40b9       ldr w8, [sp, 0x18]
0x0000e654      29010c0b       add w9, w9, w12
0x0000e658      3f01086b       cmp w9, w8
0x0000e65c      69000054       b.ls 0xe668
0x0000e660      ec1f40b9       ldr w12, [sp, 0x1c]
0x0000e664      05000014       b 0xe678
0x0000e668      c3010054       b.lo 0xe6a0
0x0000e66c      ec1f40b9       ldr w12, [sp, 0x1c]
0x0000e670      7f010c6b       cmp w11, w12
0x0000e674      6d010054       b.le 0xe6a0
0x0000e678      6b010c6b       subs w11, w11, w12
0x0000e67c      a5000054       b.pl 0xe690
0x0000e680      4a010b0b       add w10, w10, w11
0x0000e684      4b050011       add w11, w10, 1
0x0000e688      29050051       sub w9, w9, 1
0x0000e68c      e92f0229       stp w9, w11, [sp, 0x10]
0x0000e690      2801084b       sub w8, w9, w8
0x0000e694      697d4093       sxtw x9, w11
0x0000e698      682600a9       stp x8, x9, [x19]
0x0000e69c      b8ffff17       b 0xe57c
0x0000e6a0      7f7e00a9       stp xzr, xzr, [x19]
0x0000e6a4      b6ffff17       b 0xe57c
```

I don't think this is something you really want to implement yourself.

But either way, you noticed that it uses `clock_get_time`, which is not defined in that library. Indeed `clock_get_time` is in `/usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib`:

```
;-- _clock_get_time:
0x00006440      7f2303d5       pacibsp
0x00006444      ff8301d1       sub sp, sp, 0x60
0x00006448      f44f04a9       stp x20, x19, [sp, 0x40]
0x0000644c      fd7b05a9       stp x29, x30, [sp, 0x50]
0x00006450      fd430191       add x29, sp, 0x50
0x00006454      f30301aa       mov x19, x1
0x00006458      f40300aa       mov x20, x0
0x0000645c      ff7f02a9       stp xzr, xzr, [sp, 0x20]
0x00006460      ff3b00b9       str wzr, [sp, 0x38]
0x00006464      ff1b00f9       str xzr, [sp, 0x30]
0x00006468      f5eaff97       bl sym._mig_get_reply_port
0x0000646c      480100f0       adrp x8, 0x31000
0x00006470      008547fd       ldr d0, [x8, 0xf08]
0x00006474      e00700fd       str d0, [sp, 8]
0x00006478      f4030229       stp w20, w0, [sp, 0x10]
0x0000647c      480100f0       adrp x8, 0x31000
0x00006480      008947fd       ldr d0, [x8, 0xf10]
0x00006484      e00f00fd       str d0, [sp, 0x18]
0x00006488      057c60d3       lsl x5, x0, 0x20
0x0000648c      e303142a       mov w3, w20
0x00006490      037c60b3       bfi x3, x0, 0x20, 0x20
0x00006494      e0230091       add x0, sp, 8
0x00006498      610080d2       mov x1, 3
0x0000649c      4100c0f2       movk x1, 2, lsl 32
0x000064a0      62a282d2       mov x2, 0x1513
0x000064a4      0203c0f2       movk x2, 0x18, lsl 32
0x000064a8      047dc0d2       mov x4, 0x3e800000000
0x000064ac      86068052       mov w6, 0x34
0x000064b0      070080d2       mov x7, 0
0x000064b4      e8300094       bl sym._mach_msg2_internal
0x000064b8      f40300aa       mov x20, x0
0x000064bc      c8ff9f52       mov w8, 0xfffe
0x000064c0      e8ffbd72       movk w8, 0xefff, lsl 16
0x000064c4      0800080b       add w8, w0, w8
0x000064c8      1f390071       cmp w8, 0xe
0x000064cc      29008052       mov w9, 1
0x000064d0      2821c81a       lsl w8, w9, w8
0x000064d4      69008852       mov w9, 0x4003
0x000064d8      0801090a       and w8, w8, w9
0x000064dc      0499407a       ccmp w8, 0, 4, ls
0x000064e0      21040054       b.ne 0x6564
0x000064e4      94020035       cbnz w20, 0x6534
0x000064e8      e81f40b9       ldr w8, [sp, 0x1c]
0x000064ec      1f1d0171       cmp w8, 0x47
0x000064f0      80020054       b.eq 0x6540
0x000064f4      1f311171       cmp w8, 0x44c
0x000064f8      81020054       b.ne 0x6548
0x000064fc      e80b40b9       ldr w8, [sp, 8]
0x00006500      c802f837       tbnz w8, 0x1f, 0x6558
0x00006504      e80f40b9       ldr w8, [sp, 0xc]
0x00006508      1fb10071       cmp w8, 0x2c
0x0000650c      20020054       b.eq 0x6550
0x00006510      1f910071       cmp w8, 0x24
0x00006514      21020054       b.ne 0x6558
0x00006518      e82b40b9       ldr w8, [sp, 0x28]
0x0000651c      e91340b9       ldr w9, [sp, 0x10]
0x00006520      3f010071       cmp w9, 0
0x00006524      0409407a       ccmp w8, 0, 4, eq
0x00006528      69258012       mov w9, -0x12c
0x0000652c      1411891a       csel w20, w8, w9, ne
0x00006530      0b000014       b 0x655c
0x00006534      e01740b9       ldr w0, [sp, 0x14]
0x00006538      9bf6ff97       bl sym._mig_dealloc_reply_port
0x0000653c      0a000014       b 0x6564
0x00006540      74268012       mov w20, -0x134
0x00006544      06000014       b 0x655c
0x00006548      94258012       mov w20, -0x12d
0x0000654c      04000014       b 0x655c
0x00006550      e81340b9       ldr w8, [sp, 0x10]
0x00006554      28010034       cbz w8, 0x6578
0x00006558      74258012       mov w20, -0x12c
0x0000655c      e0230091       add x0, sp, 8
0x00006560      9dedff97       bl sym._mach_msg_destroy
0x00006564      e00314aa       mov x0, x20
0x00006568      fd7b45a9       ldp x29, x30, [sp, 0x50]
0x0000656c      f44f44a9       ldp x20, x19, [sp, 0x40]
0x00006570      ff830191       add sp, sp, 0x60
0x00006574      ff0f5fd6       retab
0x00006578      f42b40b9       ldr w20, [sp, 0x28]
0x0000657c      14ffff35       cbnz w20, 0x655c
0x00006580      e8c342f8       ldur x8, [sp, 0x2c]
0x00006584      680200f9       str x8, [x19]
0x00006588      f7ffff17       b 0x6564
```

Again, likely something you wouldn't want to implement by yourself in assembly.

But where does this implementation come from? You already discovered that [XNU](https://github.com/apple-oss-distributions/xnu/tags) only contains a `.defs` file. That file is a MIG (Mach Interface Generator) definitions file, which can be used to generate both client- and server-side code. To do that, you use the `mig` utility shipped with Xcode (also [open source](https://github.com/apple-oss-distributions/bootstrap_cmds/tags)). For the clocks file, the invocation would look something like this:

```
mig -novouchers -DLIBSYSCALL_INTERFACE=1 -DPRIVATE=1 -DKERNEL_SERVER=1 -arch arm64e xnu-8792.61.2/osfmk/mach/clock.defs
```

That will generate a `clock.h`, `clockServer.c` and `clockUser.c`. We only care about the last one, as it contains the userland code for `clock_get_time`:

```c
/* Routine clock_get_time */
mig_external kern_return_t clock_get_time
(
    clock_serv_t clock_serv,
    mach_timespec_t *cur_time
)
{

#ifdef  __MigPackStructs
#pragma pack(push, 4)
#endif
    typedef struct {
        mach_msg_header_t Head;
    } Request __attribute__((unused));
#ifdef  __MigPackStructs
#pragma pack(pop)
#endif

#ifdef  __MigPackStructs
#pragma pack(push, 4)
#endif
    typedef struct {
        mach_msg_header_t Head;
        NDR_record_t NDR;
        kern_return_t RetCode;
        mach_timespec_t cur_time;
        mach_msg_trailer_t trailer;
    } Reply __attribute__((unused));
#ifdef  __MigPackStructs
#pragma pack(pop)
#endif

#ifdef  __MigPackStructs
#pragma pack(push, 4)
#endif
    typedef struct {
        mach_msg_header_t Head;
        NDR_record_t NDR;
        kern_return_t RetCode;
        mach_timespec_t cur_time;
    } __Reply __attribute__((unused));
#ifdef  __MigPackStructs
#pragma pack(pop)
#endif
    /*
     * typedef struct {
     *  mach_msg_header_t Head;
     *  NDR_record_t NDR;
     *  kern_return_t RetCode;
     * } mig_reply_error_t;
     */

    union {
        Request In;
        Reply Out;
    } Mess;

    Request *InP = &Mess.In;
    Reply *Out0P = &Mess.Out;

    mach_msg_return_t msg_result;

#ifdef  __MIG_check__Reply__clock_get_time_t__defined
    kern_return_t check_result;
#endif  /* __MIG_check__Reply__clock_get_time_t__defined */

    __DeclareSendRpc(1000, "clock_get_time")

    InP->Head.msgh_reply_port = mig_get_reply_port();
    InP->Head.msgh_bits =
        MACH_MSGH_BITS(19, MACH_MSG_TYPE_MAKE_SEND_ONCE);
    InP->Head.msgh_size = (mach_msg_size_t)sizeof(Request);
    InP->Head.msgh_request_port = clock_serv;
    InP->Head.msgh_id = 1000;
    InP->Head.msgh_reserved = 0;

    __BeforeSendRpc(1000, "clock_get_time")
    msg_result = mach_msg(&InP->Head, MACH_SEND_MSG|MACH_RCV_MSG|MACH_MSG_OPTION_NONE, (mach_msg_size_t)sizeof(Request), (mach_msg_size_t)sizeof(Reply), InP->Head.msgh_reply_port, MACH_MSG_TIMEOUT_NONE, MACH_PORT_NULL);
    __AfterSendRpc(1000, "clock_get_time")
    if (msg_result != MACH_MSG_SUCCESS) {
        __MachMsgErrorWithoutTimeout(msg_result);
    }
    if (msg_result != MACH_MSG_SUCCESS) {
        { return msg_result; }
    }


#if defined(__MIG_check__Reply__clock_get_time_t__defined)
    check_result = __MIG_check__Reply__clock_get_time_t((__Reply__clock_get_time_t *)Out0P);
    if (check_result != MACH_MSG_SUCCESS) {
        mach_msg_destroy(&Out0P->Head);
        { return check_result; }
    }
#endif  /* defined(__MIG_check__Reply__clock_get_time_t__defined) */

    *cur_time = Out0P->cur_time;

    return KERN_SUCCESS;
}
```

(I omitted `__MIG_check__Reply__clock_get_time_t` here, but it is generated in the same file, right above that function.)

One thing of note here is the call to `mach_msg` though. In the assembly, we can see `mach_msg2_internal` being invoked, but the generated code simply calls `mach_msg`. If you took that code as-is and tried to run it on macOS 13 or iOS 16, it would not work. The reasons for this tie deeply into the security internals of Darwin and into a mitigation shipped in the most recent major release of Apple OSes. If you're interested in the story behind that, [Luca Todesco covered that in his Hexacon presentation](https://youtu.be/8mQAYeozl5I?t=1196) not long ago.

But by passing `-DKERNEL_SERVER=1` to `mig`, we actually made it generate a little stub for us at the beginning of the file:

```c
#include <TargetConditionals.h>
#if defined(MACH_SEND_AUX_TOO_SMALL) && (defined(__arm64__) || defined(__LP64__))
#undef mach_msg
#define mach_msg mig_mach_msg
static inline mach_msg_return_t
mig_mach_msg(
    mach_msg_header_t *msg,
    mach_msg_option_t option,
    mach_msg_size_t send_size,
    mach_msg_size_t rcv_size,
    mach_port_name_t rcv_name,
    mach_msg_timeout_t timeout,
    mach_port_name_t notify)
{
    (void)notify;
    return mach_msg2(msg, option | MACH64_SEND_KOBJECT_CALL,
        *msg, send_size, rcv_size, rcv_name, timeout, 0);
}
#endif
```

`mach_msg2` isn't defined in the public SDK either (and is not a symbol in any library), but we can steal it together from `osfmk/mach/message.h` in XNU source:

```c
typedef uint64_t mach_msg_option64_t;
#define MACH64_SEND_MSG                  MACH_SEND_MSG
#define MACH64_MSG_VECTOR        0x0000000100000000ull
#define MACH64_SEND_KOBJECT_CALL 0x0000000200000000ull

#if defined(__LP64__) || defined(__arm64__)
__API_AVAILABLE(macos(13.0), ios(16.0), tvos(16.0), watchos(9.0))
__IOS_PROHIBITED __WATCHOS_PROHIBITED __TVOS_PROHIBITED
extern mach_msg_return_t mach_msg2_internal(
    void *data,
    mach_msg_option64_t option64,
    uint64_t msgh_bits_and_send_size,
    uint64_t msgh_remote_and_local_port,
    uint64_t msgh_voucher_and_id,
    uint64_t desc_count_and_rcv_name,
    uint64_t rcv_size_and_priority,
    uint64_t timeout);

__API_AVAILABLE(macos(13.0), ios(16.0), tvos(16.0), watchos(9.0))
__IOS_PROHIBITED __WATCHOS_PROHIBITED __TVOS_PROHIBITED
static inline mach_msg_return_t
mach_msg2(
    void *data,
    mach_msg_option64_t option64,
    mach_msg_header_t header,
    mach_msg_size_t send_size,
    mach_msg_size_t rcv_size,
    mach_port_t rcv_name,
    uint64_t timeout,
    uint32_t priority)
{
    mach_msg_base_t *base;
    mach_msg_size_t descriptors;

    if (option64 & MACH64_MSG_VECTOR) {
        base = (mach_msg_base_t *)((mach_msg_vector_t *)data)->msgv_data;
    } else {
        base = (mach_msg_base_t *)data;
    }

    if ((option64 & MACH64_SEND_MSG) &&
        (base->header.msgh_bits & MACH_MSGH_BITS_COMPLEX)) {
        descriptors = base->body.msgh_descriptor_count;
    } else {
        descriptors = 0;
    }

#define MACH_MSG2_SHIFT_ARGS(lo, hi) ((uint64_t)hi << 32 | (uint32_t)lo)
    return mach_msg2_internal(data, option64,
               MACH_MSG2_SHIFT_ARGS(header.msgh_bits, send_size),
               MACH_MSG2_SHIFT_ARGS(header.msgh_remote_port, header.msgh_local_port),
               MACH_MSG2_SHIFT_ARGS(header.msgh_voucher_port, header.msgh_id),
               MACH_MSG2_SHIFT_ARGS(descriptors, rcv_name),
               MACH_MSG2_SHIFT_ARGS(rcv_size, priority), timeout);
#undef MACH_MSG2_SHIFT_ARGS
}
#endif
```

This then goes through `mach_msg2_internal`, which is defined in `libsyscall/mach/mach_msg.c` and compiled into `libsystem_kernel.dylib`, and that calls down to `mach_msg2_trap`, which, at long long last, is where the `svc` happens:

```
;-- _mach_msg2_trap:
0x00000d68      d0058092       mov x16, -0x2f
0x00000d6c      011000d4       svc 0x80
0x00000d70      c0035fd6       ret
```

I guess with this you could build your own `nanosleep` on macOS 13 or iOS 16 now. It wouldn't work on versions before those though (you'd have to use plain `mach_msg` there), and an implementation that did work on those wouldn't work on macOS 13 and iOS 16, so you probably really shouldn't. Just call the libc implementation.

Comment: Thank you for a wonderfully thorough reply!